# How to fix ReferenceError in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How can I fix ReferenceError? I am trying to display records in Kendo Grid. I used the following code. I am trying to pass a textbox value to MVC action but jQuery is giving me a ReferenceError:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TestProject.ViewModels.Project.gridModel>()
    .Name("BillDocuments")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden().Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Sequence).Title("Seg").Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DocumentType).Width(100);    
        columns.Bound(m => m.Actions).ClientTemplate("<a class='text-primary' href='#= Location #'>View</a>").Width(50);  

    })   
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()        
        .PageSize(5)
         .Read(read => read.Action("BillRead", "Billing", new { Area = "Billing"}).Data("additionalInfo")
         .Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
     )
)
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
    function additionalInfo() {
        return {
            invoiceID: $("#txtInvoiceID").val(),

        }
    }      
</script>
```

But it keeps giving me **ReferenceError: additionalInfo is not defined[Learn More]**

Comment: This could be because the `additionalInfo` function isnt declared yet (so script runs before the function is created), or its out of scope. Try using `window.additionalInfo` to see if it can find that.

Comment: As I dont know Kendo UI, cant help much there, but shouldnt you be using `invoiceID` somewhere? Because youre returning an object that hold `invoiceID`'s value

Comment: What are the parameters of your action? Your passing both "Area" and "invoiceID". See example here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-parameters-to-read-ajax-datasource-method---mvc

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes, i need area and invoice ID, I was working  based on the link on your comment, the problem is i used nameof() and that return text instead of textbox value when i used `window.additionalInfo` gets textbox value but return ID instead of value

Comment: `.val()` should work for a standard input/textbox.  Is it a kendo textbox by chance? if so, you need `$("#txtInvoiceID").data("kendoTextBox").value()`

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you, still the same i think i can see the value in the textbox since nameof() return string it just grab `ID` instead of whats in the textbox  is there anyways to call the function after the page full load may be thats why?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be nice to see broader context of your View, but the suggestion from comment is actually correct. I'm quite sure you define your grid **before** the script tag (usually, `<script>`s are at the end in classic MVC). I believe that when Razor translates your template into HTML, it simply injects some HTML elements with additional script tag. Apparently, it uses `additionalInfo` function, which isn't defined yet. Here's an example which will render exactly same error as in your case:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<script>
    console.log(foo());
</script>
<script>
    function foo() {
        return 'foo';
    }
</script>
</iframe>
</html>
```

Possible fix is to simply move the `<script>` tag where `additionalInfo` is defined to the top of your page (considering **the definition** itself does not have any dependency on the DOM, you can safely do that). The function **call**, however, should be done after the DOM is ready.